# How to cancel a HTTPRequest in Angular 2?

Tags: http, promise, angular

How to cancel a HTTPRequest in Angular 2?

I know how to reject the request promise only.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.currentLoading.set(url, {resolve, reject});

    this.http.get(url, {headers: reqHeaders})
        .subscribe(
            (res) => {
                res = res.json();

                this.currentLoading.delete(url);
                this.cache.set(url, res);

                resolve(res);
            }
        );
});
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can call `unsubscribe`

```
let sub = this.http.get(url, {headers: reqHeaders})
            .subscribe(
                (res) => {
                    res = res.json();

                    this.currentLoading.delete(url);
                    this.cache.set(url, res);

                    resolve(res);
                }
            );

sub.unsubscribe();
```

More info here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-and-http

Comment: This answer is not longer valid in beta.15. There is no `unsubscribe` method in Observable now.

Comment: `unsubscribe` was replaced by `dispose`.

Comment: I'm using RC.5 of Angular2, and `unsubscribe` is present (version 5.0.0-beta.6 of rxjs). Perhaps it was restored since the comments were made? Not sure where the discrepancy is coming from.

Comment: @DawsonToth Angular 2 team hasn't updated rxjs from a long time, it will be updated in RC6

Comment: could somebody provide a live example and we close the question about `unsubscribe ` / `dispose `

Comment: What is unsubscribing all of a sudden stops cancelling the request? What can be the problem?

Comment: This is actually not correct. The service will unsubscribe before it even completes. Not sure why this was marked as correct answer by so many.

Answer (score 104):

You can use the following simple solution:

```
if ( this.subscription ) {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
this.subscription = this.http.get( 'awesomeApi' )
 .subscribe((res)=> {
  // your awesome code..
})
```

Comment: works great with Angular 2.4.6 - This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Is it possible to be done via `.toPromise()` method and `then()`, `catch()`?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati why do you need to be done via promise ?

Comment: what is the type of this.subscription??

Comment: @SunilGarg are you asking for subscription: Subscription; ?

Comment: I declared `subscription:Subscriber<any>` but this is showing error, what should be the type of `this.subscription`

Comment: Maaan use a switchMap :D

Comment: Typo of this.subscription is Subscription from rxJs.

I would correct first line to `if ( this.subscription && !this.subscription.closed ) {` to check if it was already been unsubscribed

Comment: This solution seems to be just canceling the subscription to the observable, but if the httpRequest was sent and process by the API is not really canceling the request, just the reaction - is there a way to cancel the request before if finishes

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez Can you tell me more about your use case? Do you need this for large file uploads?

Comment: I basically want to cancer the request before it finishes - I have mentioned a specific case here but is as i have mentioned - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70601775/how-to-cancel-an-httpclient-delete-request-before-it-finishes

Answer (score 10):

You can use SwitchMap on the observable which will cancel any previous request's responses and only request the latest:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Comment: How? Can you give us an example?

Answer (score 9):

A little late for the party, but here is my take:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Http } from '@angular/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import { Subscriber } from 'rxjs/Subscriber'

@Injectable ()
export class SomeHttpServiceService {
  private subscriber: Subscriber<any>
  constructor(private http: Http){ }

  public cancelableRequest() {
    let o = new Observable(obs => subscriber = obs)
    return this.http.get('someurl').takeUntil(o)
      .toPromise() //I dont like observables
      .then(res => {
        o.unsubscribe
        return res
      })
  }
  public cancelRequest() {
    subscriber.error('whatever')
  }
}
```

This allows you to manually cancel a request. I sometimes end up with an observable or promise that will make changes to a result on the page. If the request was initiated automatically (user didn't type anyting in a field for x millis) being able to abort the request is nice (user is suddenly typing something again)...

takeUntil should also work with a simple timeout (Observable.timer) if that is what you are looking for
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil

Comment: Why don't u like observables? For http it is the same like promise, but also has error and complete

Comment: @Mick, I think clearfix was just accommodating the OP's preference for promises, not expressing his/her opinion. #theSpiritOfStackOverflow

Answer (score 6):

Use `switchMap` [[docs]](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap), which will cancel all in-flight requests and use only the latest.

```
get(endpoint: string): Observable<any> {
        const headers: Observable<{url: string, headers: HttpHeaders}> = this.getConfig();
        return headers.pipe(
            switchMap(obj => this.http.get(`${obj.url}${endpoint}`, { headers: obj.headers, params: params }) ),
            shareReplay(1)
        );
    }
```

[shareReplay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) will emit the latest value for any late subscribers.

Comment: how to do it if I do't have any observable link your `headers`. I have http call made on click of button but from the docs, I can only use `switchMap` on observable

Answer (score 2):

This is a great thread, and I have a little more info to provide. I have an API call that could potentially go on for a very long time. So I needed the previous request to cancel with a timeout. I just figured out today that I can add a `timeout` operator to the pipe function. Once the timeout completes its count, that will cancel the previous HTTP request.

Example...

```js
return this.exampleHttpRequest()
  .pipe(
    timeout(3000),
    catchError(err => console.log(error)
)
```