# how to abort and "resolve" a subscription immediately in rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, abort, rxjs5

New to rxjs and angular2. How do I abort an http call and return an observable so I don't get an error on the subscription end? of course if I just return an object here, we get `.searchAlbum(...).subscribe is not a function`

```
public searchAlbum (term:string, queryObject?:any) {

    if( this.abortSearches){
      queryObject.body = null;
      return //what to return here? used to be deferred.resolve(queryObject);
    }

    ...

    return this.http.request( new Request( options ) )
        .map(res => this.extractData(res, queryObject) )
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: The context for this code is not clear. It possibly should be `return Observable.of(queryObject)`. As for request cancellation, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490926/how-to-cancel-a-httprequest-in-angular-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your situation you want to return an Observable even though the `this.abortSearches` is `true` and therefore you don't want to make any actual HTTP request. However, you have some other functionality tied to this method so you want it to always return an Observable.

You can return [`Observable.empty()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-empty) which is an Observable that emits no values an just signals complete.