# Cancel pending http requests in Angular 4/Ionic 3

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework

We have an app that pulls users schedules on a per day basis. They can side scroll through days and on each scroll stop it fires the `http.get` and grabs the schedule for that day.

The problem we have run into is people scrolling, lifting their finger and continuing scrolling. We implemented a timeout so there is a delay between slide stop and the request firing, but we can't make that too long and still a number of `http.get` requests are fired.

I need a way to cancel any pending HTTP requests on the start of a new one.

```
slideStop() {
   ..gather date information and other relevant parameters..

   <stop any pending HTTP requests>

   this.http.get()
}
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490926/how-to-cancel-a-httprequest-in-angular-2 about unsubscribe from HTTP

Comment: Thanks that worked beautifully @AmrElAdawy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `switchMap` on an observable, it will cancel any pending requests when you re-use this observable as mentioned in the documentation (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#activatedroute-the-one-stop-shop-for-route-information)

> The switchMap operator allows you to perform an action with the current value of the Observable, and map it to a new Observable. As with many rxjs operators, switchMap handles an Observable as well as a Promise to retrieve the value they emit.
>
> The switchMap operator will also cancel any in-flight requests if the user re-navigates to the route while still retrieving a hero.