# How to cancel previous http request when type in search bar

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I want to add some delay in making network request when I type in search bar. So I can prevent unnecessary network request.

header.component.ts

```
searchProduct(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event) {
      const { value } = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
      this.productService.searchProducts(value).subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        if (res.length > 5) {
          res.length = 5;
        }
        this.searchResult = res;
      });
    }
```

product.service.ts

```
searchProducts(query: string) {
    return this.http.get<Prodcut[]>(`http://localhost:3000/products?q=${query}`);
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cancel a HTTPRequest in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490926/how-to-cancel-a-httprequest-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 2):

The switchMap will cancel any HTTP request that hasn't been completed if a new value is emitted through the subject. You can play with the debouneTime to see what feels right for you.

```
this.searchBar.on('change', () => {

    of(this.serachBar.searchText).pipe(
        debounceTime(400),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap((text) => {
            return this.productService.searchProducts(text).map(resp => {
                console.log(res);
                if (res.length > 5) {
                    res.length = 5;
                }
                return res;
            });
        });
    ).subscribe(response => console.log(response));

});
```

Comment: I am trying with this code but no matter how much is debounce time I gave, still I'm getting immediate console logs. can you please telll what is wrong I'm doing here?

searchProduct(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event) {
      const { value } = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
      if (value !== '') {
        of(value)
          .pipe(debounceTime(40000))
          .subscribe((res) => {
            console.log(`res is ${res}`);
          });
      }
    }
  }

Comment: <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a value" name="foo" [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" (ngModelChange)="onFieldChange($event)">

searchQuery: string; // bind this to input with ngModel
searchQueryChanged: Subject < string > = new Subject<string>();

onFieldChange(query: string){
    this.searchQueryChanged.next(query);
}

Comment: //add this inside ngOnInit
this.searchQueryChanged.pipe(
    debounceTime(400),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap((text) => {
        return this.productService.searchProducts(text).map(resp => {
            console.log(res);
            if (res.length > 5) {
                res.length = 5;
            }
            return res;
        });
    })
).subscribe(response => console.log(response));

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to cancel the previous request, but to make a delay, if you want to prevent unnecessary network request. Something like this:

```js
this.changeValue$
  .pipe(debounceTime(300))
  .subscribe((event) => {
    this.searchProduct(event);
  });
```

But in this case, you need to modify the input.

If you still want to cancel, then try:

```js
subsription: Subscription | undefined;

searchProduct(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (event) {
    this.subsription?.unsubscribe();
    const { value } = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    this.subsription = this.productService.searchProducts(value).subscribe((res) => {
    // ...
}
```