# Angular observable returns after navigate to another page

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

How to abort a return from a rxjs call to backend, when the user navigate to another page before the result returns?

In example below, it shows the alert message even if another page is already loaded.

```
this.http.get('api/searchforanything', {
  params: {
    data: this.dateService.toLocalISOString(data)
  }
}).subscribe(x => {
    alert("I am back!");
    this.chartLabels = x.meses;
    this.data = x.valores;
    this.isLoading = false;
    
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the request is cancelable, it will be canceled when you unsubscribe. Else the result is just ignored. [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40150392/6236935) You can either write your logic with navigation events from the router or just unsubscribe when your component gets destroyed, which is a good practice in angular anyways.

```
this.http.get('api/searchforanything', {
  params: {
    data: this.dateService.toLocalISOString(data)
  }
})
.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
.subscribe(x => {
...
```